# Scheduler configuration

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, scheduler

It is posible that the end user configure things like the resource headers, time scale limits, background colors for resources or appointments, things like that? or the scheduler is just configurable by the designer/programmer?

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to write some custom functionality for end users to change that options.

Comment: Thanks Pawel I'm on it.

Comment: If you know some examples that can share I really appreciate it.